# Integration of the Fermi distribution using Python

Tags: python, scipy, integration

I want to calculate the carrier concentration of my semiconductor using this equation:

$$
n(x) = \frac{m^*}{\pi\hbar^2}\int_{E_k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{E-E_f}{k_BT}\right)} \mathrm{d}E
$$

I'm using this straightforward scipy approach:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants as phys
import scipy.integrate as integrate

eigenvalue = [0.9 * phys.electron_volt, 1.3 * phys.electron_volt]
fermi = 1.0 * phys.electron_volt
T = 300

def fermi_integral(E, fermi, T):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp((E - fermi) / (phys.Boltzmann * T)))

for i in range(len(eigenvalue)):
    result = integrate.quad(fermi_integral, eigenvalue[i], np.inf, args=(fermi, T))
    print(result)
```

However, I'm running into

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp((E - fermi) / (phys.Boltzmann * T)))
```

and my result is always `(0.0, 0.0)`

I guess I have to use another approach, but I'm stuck and I hope you can give me some helpful input.

Comment: Numerical integration methods usually assume that your function changes meaningfully on the scale of the interval you give it, which is something like $(0,1)$ here. But your function is almost identically zero from $100\times k_B T$ onwards, so trying to evaluate it at a default value of e.g. $\frac12$ causes an error. If there were no overflow, it would still give a bad result because the function values would be indistinguishable from zero on all the default values `quad` tries at first. That's why rescaling can fix this as in nicoguaro's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of your problems is the system of units that you are using. Just changing the units improves the results

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

eigenvalue = [0.9, 1.3]
fermi = 1.0
T = 300
kB = 8.6173303e-5


def fermi_integral(E, fermi, T):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp((E - fermi) / (kB * T)))


for i in range(len(eigenvalue)):
    result = integrate.quad(fermi_integral, eigenvalue[i], np.inf,
                            args=( fermi, T))
    print(result)
```

These are the results

```
(0.10053464900138948, 1.2260194855049155e-09)
(2.3589139312840435e-07, 4.1489077967047375e-11)
```

I still get the overflow problem, but that is probably because you are evaluating the functions for really large numbers. I just replaced `np.inf` for 10 and obtained the same results.

#### Edit

Taking into account @gammatester suggestion the overflow warning does not appear anymore. The following works for me.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

eigenvalue = [0.9, 1.3]
fermi = 1.0
T = 300
kB = 8.6173303e-5


def fermi_integral(E, fermi, T):
    if E < fermi:
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp((E - fermi) / (kB * T)))
    else:
        return np.exp(-(E - fermi) / (kB * T)) / (1 + np.exp(-(E - fermi) / (kB * T)))


for i in range(len(eigenvalue)):
    result = integrate.quad(fermi_integral, eigenvalue[i], np.inf,
                            args=( fermi, T))
    print(result)
```

Comment: Or you can transform the integand so that no overflow occurs for large $x:$
$$\frac{1}{1+e^x}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}$$

Comment: @gammatester, that works. Although, one has to find what "large $x$" means. In this case it seems that 300 is large enough.

Comment: You can always use it, it is valid for all $x;$ but it would overflow for large negative $x$.  I would use it if $x>0$ and the original for $x\le0,$ i.e. if $E>E_f$.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is already answered satisfactorily, but let me just add this gentle reminder to check whether the integral can be done analytically, before crunching it with a numerical method! In this case the indefinite integral of 
$$
f(E) = \frac{1}{1+\exp[(E-E_f)/k_B T]}
$$
is this:
$$
F(E) = -k_B T \ln \left\{ 1+\exp[-(E-E_f)/k_B T] \right\}
$$
and $F(\infty)=0$, so the desired answer is $-F(E_k)$. The following python code

```
import numpy as np

eigenvalue = np.array([0.9, 1.3])
fermi = 1.0
T = 300
kB = 8.6173303e-5

result = kB*T*np.log(1+np.exp(-(eigenvalue-fermi)/(kB*T)))
print(result)
```

gives the exact result(s), for comparison with the numerical one(s).

```
[1.00534649e-01 2.35891393e-07]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advocate on using the `scipy.stats.logistic.sf` as the Fermi-Dirac distribution.

The Fermi-Dirac is equivalent to the logistics *survival function* (otherwise known as `complementary cumulative distribution function`).
The benefits of using the above is that you'll have immediate access to many different methods accessible through distribution function interfaces in scipy + it handles many corner cases by examining input arguments. As is the case here where it uses `scipy.special.expit` to calculate these corner cases.

What is nice, is that one can draw samples from the FD distribution around some energy.